# How to consume SAP Service Reference from ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm newest in this type of projects and I need some help. I have a ASPX app that must consum a SAP Services over SOAP. The third partner provide me the wsdl file to attach de service.
OK, when I add the service reference based on the WSDL, in my web.config the next files are added:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ZWSDISLINEPEDIDOS" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://SomeURL" binding="basicHttpBinding"            bindingConfiguration="ZWSDISLINEPEDIDOS"
        contract="WS_SAP_PEDIDOS.ZWSDISLINEPEDIDOS" name="ZWSDISLINEPEDIDOS" />

    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And my .cs has the next code:

```
     BasicHttpBinding _Binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://SomeURL");

            ZWSDISLINEPEDIDOSClient _Client = new ZWSDISLINEPEDIDOSClient(_Binding, address);
            _Client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "MyUserName";
            _Client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "MyPassword";

When we try to call a method from the client the next error fires:
```

"a solicitud HTTP no está autorizada con el esquema de autenticación de cliente 'Anonymous'. El encabezado de autenticación recibido del servidor era 'Basic realm="SAP NetWeaver Application Server [LP1/100]"'

Any idea?

Comment: You should translate the error message in english

Comment: Sorry: HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme ' Anonymous ' . The authentication header received from the server was ' Basic realm = "SAP NetWeaver Application Server [ LP1 / 100 ]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the webservice you are trying to call does not allow anonymous authentication. Instead the webservice has got just the basic authentication enabled.

To understand how authentication works for WCF you can read a very good 2-parts article: [part 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405740.aspx) and [part 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406125.aspx).

Moreover [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733775(v=vs.110).aspx) you can find a complete sample (with both server and client side).

I cannot reproduce your situation, but it seems that:

1. you should use `WSHttpBinding` instead of `BasicHttpBinding`
2. in your code, you are not setting the `ClientCredentialType` property of your binding (i.e. `_Binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
   HttpClientCredentialType.Basic`)

I hope my hints can help you in solving your issue.